Iterate through large XML data while multiprocessing using Python
I have to periodically check a big XML file with millions of records.
context = iter(etree.iterparse(product_file_path, tag="Record", events=("start", "end")))
_, root = next(context)
start_tag = None
xml_dict = None
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == "start" and start_tag is None:
            start_tag = elem.tag
        if event == "end":
            pickled_elem = etree.tostring(elem)  # This will make sense later
            xml_dict = _etree_to_dict(pickled_elem)
            _update_product(self.category, xml_dict)
            start_tag = None
            xml_dict = None
            root.clear()

While I managed to loop through the file using lxml without blowing my RAM, it takes too long, so I was trying to multithread this.
I'm very new to multithreading and I managed to cobble together a solution using Django management commands and with the help of this answer
ProcPoolExc = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor
ThreadPoolExc = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        # ( other unnecessary code)

        context = iter(etree.iterparse(product_file_path, tag="Detail", events=("start", "end")))
        _, root = next(context)
        start_tag = None
        xml_dict = None
        xml_dict_futures = []
        product_update_futures = []

        with ProcPoolExc(max_workers=threads) as ppe, ThreadPoolExc(max_workers=threads) as tpe:
            for event, elem in context:
                if event == "start" and start_tag is None:
                    start_tag = elem.tag
                if event == "end":
                    xml_dict_futures.append(ppe.submit(_etree_to_dict, elem))
                    start_tag = None
                    root.clear()

            for future in futures.as_completed(xml_dict_futures):
                xml_dict = future.result()
                product_update_futures.append(tpe.submit(_update_product, *(self.category, xml_dict)))

            for fut in futures.as_completed(product_update_futures):
                e = fut.exception()
                print("success" if not e else e)

This works. However, it threw me back to the same Memory problem when dealing with large XML files in which I wait for a time until it crashes my computer due to insufficient RAM. I suppose it's because I'm saving everything in xml_dict_futures and product_update_futures? Is there a way I could optimize this to avoid this issue?
I tried to use an intermediary function and ThreadPoolExecutor.map, but I guess I'm doing it wrong because it stops and it doesn't show anything
def _queue_update(default_category, start_tag, root, event, elem):
    if event == "start" and start_tag is None:
        start_tag = elem.tag
    if event == "end":
        pickled_elem = etree.tostring(elem)
        _update_product(default_category, pickled_elem)
        start_tag = None
        root.clear()

and then
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(threads) as executor:
    executor.map(
        _queue_update, [(self.category, start_tag, root, event, elem) for event, elem in context]
    )


Does the file change when you periodically need to read from it? Anyway, have you considered using an XML database like BaseX to store the file and then do the processing in XQuery and just have a Python client program getting the data from BaseX?

@MartinHonnen It doesn't, a file gets periodically downloaded from a supplier and I need to iterate through it to import it to a Django project using PostgreSQL. Using BaseX doesn't fit my case
